# grep but indexable?

Tags: linux, grep

I have over 200mb of source code files that I have to constantly look up (I am part of a very big team). I notice that grep does not create an index so lookup requires going through the entire source code database each time.

Is there a command line utility similar to grep which has indexing ability?

Comment: Have you considered http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: One tip to significantly speed up `grep` if you're only dealing with ASCII files is to set `LANG=C` before you run it.

Comment: @Johnnsyweb, Well if I know I am using a specific language then ctags would kind of make sense. However I am dealing with large amounts of protocol buffers, xml, configs, java, and pretty much everything kind of config file that you can imagine. I have used ctags before strictly for kernel development but I don't recall using ctags for the purpose of grep.

Comment: This is why I provided Ctags merely as a comment. I realise it didn't answer your question, but depending on the actual details of your problem it could be an elegant solution.

Comment: Not aswer but: what about moving that source code to ramdisk?

Comment: can you give and example of your grep command? also, do you have a CPU or a I/O bottleneck?

Comment: At least, with git 2.8 (Q1 2016), you will be able to launch grep in parallel: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34762575/6309): `git grep --threads 2 ...`

Answer (score 11):

The solutions below are rather simple. There are a lot of corner cases that they do not cover:

- searching for start of line ^
- filenames containing \n or : will fail
- filenames containing white space will fail (though that can be fixed by using GNU Parallel instead of xargs)
- searching for a string that matches the path of another files will be suboptimal

The good part about the solutions is that they are very easy to implement.

**Solution 1: one big file**

Fact: Seeking is dead slow, reading one big file is often faster.

Given those facts the idea is to simply make an index containing all the files with all their content - each line prepended with the filename and the line number:

Index a dir:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Han . > .index
```

Use the index:

```
grep foo .index
```

**Solution 2: one big compressed file**

Fact: Harddrives are slow. Seeking is dead slow. Multi core CPUs are normal.

So it may be faster to read a compressed file and decompress it on the fly than reading the uncompressed file - especially if you have RAM enough to cache the compressed file but not enough for the uncompressed file.

Index a dir:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Han . | pbzip2 > .index
```

Use the index:

```
pbzcat .index | grep foo
```

**Solution 3: use index for finding potential candidates**

Generating the index can be time consuming and you might not want to do that for every single change in the dir.

To speed that up only use the index for identifying filenames that might match and do an actual grep through those (hopefully limited number of) files. This will discover files that no longer match, but it will not discover new files that do match.

The `sort -u` is needed to avoid grepping the same file multiple times.

Index a dir:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Han . | pbzip2 > .index
```

Use the index:

```
pbzcat .index | grep foo | sed s/:.*// | sort -u | xargs grep foo
```

**Solution 4: append to the index**

Re-creating the full index can be very slow. If most of the dir stays the same, you can simply append to the index with newly changed files. The index will again only be used for locating potential candidates, so if a file no longer matches it will be discovered when grepping through the actual file.

Index a dir:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Han . | pbzip2 > .index
```

Append to the index:

```
find . -type f -newer .index -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Han . | pbzip2 >> .index
```

Use the index:

```
pbzcat .index | grep foo | sed s/:.*// | sort -u | xargs grep foo
```

It can be even faster if you use `pzstd` instead of `pbzip2`/`pbzcat`.

**Solution 5: use git**

`git grep` can grep through a git repository. But it seems to do a lot of seeks and is 4 times slower on my system than solution 4.

The good part is that the .git index is smaller than the .index.bz2.

Index a dir:

```
git init
git add .
```

Append to the index:

```
git add .
```

Use the index:

```
git grep foo
```

**Solution 6: optimize git**

Git puts its data into many small files. This results in seeking. But you can ask git to compress the small files into few, bigger files:

```
git gc --aggressive
```

This takes a while, but it packs the index very efficiently in few files.

Now you can do:

```
find .git  -type f | xargs cat >/dev/null
git grep foo
```

`git` will do a lot of seeking into the index, but by running `cat` first, you put the whole index into RAM.

Adding to the index is the same as in solution 5, but run `git gc` now and then to avoid many small files, and `git gc --aggressive` to save more disk space, when the system is idle.

`git` will not free disk space if you remove files. So if you remove large amounts of data, remove `.git` and do `git init; git add .` again.

Answer (score 3):

There is https://code.google.com/p/codesearch/ project which is capable of creating index and fast searching in the index. Regexps are supported and computed using index (actually, only subset of regexp can use index to filter file set, and then real regexp is reevaluted on the matched files).

Index from codesearch is usually 10-20% of source code size, building an index is fast like running classic grep 2 or 3 times, and the searching is almost instantaneous.

The ideas used in the codesearch project are from google's Code Search site (RIP). E.g. the index contains map from n-grams (3-grams or every 3-byte set found in your sources) to the files; and regexp is translated to 4-grams when searching.

PS And there are ctags and cscope to navigate in C/C++ sources. Ctags can find declarations/definitions, cscope is more capable, but has problems with C++.

PPS and there are also clang-based tools for C/C++/ObjC languages: http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2011/10/vim-plugin-for-navigating-c-with.html and clang-complete

Answer (score 3):

> I notice that grep does not create an index so lookup requires going through the entire source code database each time.

Without addressing the indexing ability part, git grep will have, with Git 2.8 (Q1 2016) the abililty to run in parallel!

See [commit 89f09dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89f09dd34e613394c749f69ddd74adc90cb034ca), [commit 044b1f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/044b1f3cb4ff09551f6c514ed02edafa6c4987b0), [commit b6b468b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6b468b2bfaa8015568efad8e0a78b342e1ac640) (15 Dec 2015) by [Victor Leschuk (`vleschuk`)](https://github.com/vleschuk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bdd1cc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdd1cc20929e9f7631dd29ff70426eea53f69443), 12 Jan 2016)</sup>

> ### `grep`: add `--threads=<num>` option and `grep.threads` configuration
>
> "`git grep`" can now be configured (or told from the command line) how
>   many threads to use when searching in the working tree files.

```
grep.threads:
```

> Number of `grep` worker threads to use.

Comment: Looks like this GNU Grep 3.4 (2021) doesn't have this.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Agreed. This is about `git grep`, not GNU `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

ack is a code searching tool that is optimized for programmers, especially programmers dealing with large heterogeneous source code trees: http://beyondgrep.com/

Is some of your search examples where you only want to search a certain type of file, like only Java files?  Then you can do

```
ack --java function
```

ack does not index the source code, but it may not matter depending on what your searching patterns are like.  In many cases, only searching for certain types of files gives the speedup that you need because you're not also searching all those other XML, etc files.

And if ack doesn't do it for you, here is a list of many tools designed for searching source code: http://beyondgrep.com/more-tools/

Answer (score 1):

We use a tool internally to index very large log files and make efficient searches of them.  It has been open-sourced.  I don't know how well it scales to large numbers of files, though.  It multithreads by default, it searches inside gzipped files, and it caches indexes of previously searched files.

https://github.com/purestorage/4grep

Answer (score 0):

This  [grep-cache](http://bradbeveridge.wordpress.com/2007/06/07/grep-cache/) article has a script for caching grep results. His examples were run on windows with linux tools installed, so it can easily be used on nix/mac with little modification.  It's  mostly just a perl script anyway.

Also, the filesystem itself (assuming your using *nix) often caches recently read data, causing future grep times to be faster since grep is effectively searching virt memory instead of disk.

The cache is usually located in `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` if you want manually erase it to see the speed increase from an uncached to a cached grep.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention various kinds of text files that are not really code, I suggest you have a look at [GNU ID utils](https://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/manual/idutils.html). For example:

```
cd /tmp
# create index file named 'ID'
mkid -m /dev/null  -d text /var/log/messages.*
# query index
gid -r 'spamd|kernel'
```

These tools focus on tokens, so queries on strings of tokens are not possible. There is minimal integration in emacs for the gid command.

For the more specific case of indexing source code, I prefer to use [GNU global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/), which I find more flexible. For example:

```
cd sourcedir
# index source tree
gtags .
# look for a definition
global -x main
# look for a reference
global -xr printf
# look for another kind of symbol
global -xs argc
```

Global natively supports C/C++ and Java, and with a bit of configuration, can be extended to support many more languages. It also has very good integration with emacs: successive queries are stacked, and updating a source file updates the index efficiently. However I'm not aware that it is able to index plain text (yet).